# How can I search for repeating characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that checks for repeating characters in a string and prints false if repetition is found. Something like 'hello16' or 'secret77' would be invalid passwords.

What I have so far

```
def password_check():
    if pw.isalpha() == True:
        print('Password must contain at least one number.')
    elif pw.isdigit() == True:
        print('Password must contain at least one letter. ')
    else:
        print('True')
pw = input('Enter new password: ') 

 #--------------------------------------------------- revised code below

def password_check(pw):
if len(pw) < 2:
    print ('Password must be at least 2 characters long')
elif pw.isalpha():
    print('Password must contain at least one number.')
    return False
elif pw.isdigit():
    print('Password must contain at least one letter. ')
    return False
for a in pw:
    if a * 2 in pw:
        print('Password contains a consecutive character')
        return False
print('Password was accepted')
return True

pw = input('Enter new password: ')
password_check(pw) # Call your function
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working? Can you post your code as part of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be this one:

```
def password_check(pw):
    if len(pw) < 2:
        print ('Password must be at least 2 characters long')
        return False
    elif pw.isalpha():
        print('Password must contain at least one number.')
        return False
    elif pw.isdigit():
        print('Password must contain at least one letter. ')
        return False
    for a in pw:
        if a * 2 in pw:
            print('Password contains a consecutive character')
            return False
    print('Password was accepted')
    return True
```

Simply check if any character which appears in the password is exists twice consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def password_check(pw):
    if not pw:
        print('Please enter a password')
    elif pw.isalpha():
        print('Password must contain at least one number.')
    elif pw.isdigit():
        print('Password must contain at least one letter. ')
    elif any((len(list(vals)) > 1) for (char, vals) in groupby(pw)):
        print('Password cannot contain duplicate characters. ')
    else:
        print('True')


pw = input('Enter new password: ')
password_check(pw) # Call your function
```

Comment: Thanks! Just had another question. I forgot to add the input() at the bottom of the line code and it's not printing. Where should I move it to? I just added it to the code above.

Comment: @Regis_ see edited answer

Comment: wouldn't this code reject a legit password like 'abac1234' because 'a' appears twice although it is not repetitive?

Comment: @Ashafix, good point. Regis, what do you mean by repetitive? You can't have the same character repeated anywhere or you can't have the character repeated in a row?

Comment: Maybe I should have worded it better. I should have said consecutive.

Comment: @Ashafix, Regis_, updated

Comment: entering an empty password will be accepted as a valid password.

Comment: ''.isalpha returns False in Python 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: Good point updated, idk what I was thinking

Comment: So combined what @Ashafix and Bahrom posted. I think thats what I was looking for. I really appreciate everyone's help!